# E - Commerce open source review

Tags: open-source, e-commerce

Do you know a good review of the existing e-commerce open source platforms? I'll like it to be written in PHP in order to understand them faster and to contribute back.

many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [Zen Cart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zen_Cart) or [osCommerce](http://www.oscommerce.com/). Both are widley supported and have a large community base.

Answer (score 1):

Magento Shopping Cart- they are using Zend Framework.

Magento is replacing other open source cart, and becoming the best, in terms of functionality and interface.